# Implement EmailService to notify User when Admin answer on post

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am looking for some `EmailService` which will notify user when Admin answer on `his/her` post.
I have HelDesk Web App which is done in `ASP.NET CORE MVC` and so far I have Dicussion which Admin can answer on User ticket. And whenever Admin answer in ticket User should get notification in email.

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SendDiscussion(int ticketId, string message)
        {
            var userName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            var account = _db.ApplicationUsers.SingleOrDefault(a => a.UserName.Equals(userName));

            var discussion = new Discussion
            {
                DateAndTime = DateTime.Now,
                Content = message,
                TicketId = ticketId,
                UserId = account.Id,
                ApplicationUser = account
            };
            _unitOfwork.Discussion.Add(discussion);
            _unitOfwork.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = ticketId });
        }
```

Email should be sent only to user which post ticket. Currently I have around 10 users, but this number will increase up to 100 user.
I check  this post but I am not sure is this `MailKit` good solution

[Reference](https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-core-send-email-messages-smtp-mailkit/)

Anyone who can guide me and tell me is MailKit good solution for this purpose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend `FluentEmail` library, it is pretty simple to integrate and give you everything you want.

Here is the open-source project: https://github.com/lukencode/FluentEmail

When you install this package to your project it is easy to use:

```
public IActionResult SendDiscussion(int ticketId, string message)
{
    // Your code

    // Email variable should be passed as dependency injection or directly created here
    await email
        .To("test@test.test")
        .Subject("test email subject")
        .Body("This is the email body")
        .SendAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Emin for you advice and help. I will try this solution

Comment: One more question.  `To("test@test.test")` I should pass only email which user is logged in. How to do this ? I have ApplicationUser class and email should be sent only to user which submit post.

Comment: That's the business logic side, you have to handle that part to retrieve logged users and just provide an email to this part of the code.

You have here some kind of instructions: https://lukelowrey.com/send-email-in-dotnet-core-with-fluent-email/